# React: Filter multidimensional array object by value in component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have an array of objects like this:

```
var matchs = [
    {
      id: 10689,
      sport: 'Tennis',
      players: [
        {
        id: 22,
        name:'Rafa Nadal',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: {
            bookie_1: 1.60,
            bookie_2: 1.61,
            bookie_3: 1.62
          }
        },
        {
        id: 23,
        name:'Roger Federer',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: {
            bookie_1: 2.30,
            bookie_2: 2.31,
            bookie_3: 2.32
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 12389,
      sport: 'Tennis',
      players: [
        {
        id: 45,
        name:'Fernando Verdasco',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: {
            bookie_1: 3.20,
            bookie_2: 3.21,
            bookie_3: 3.22
          }
        },
        {
        id: 65,
        name:'Andy Murray',
        country: 'Spain',
        odds: {
            bookie_1: 1.20,
            bookie_2: 1.21,
            bookie_3: 1.22
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

And I have a React Component that shows all matchs with `map` inside `map` . I have tried to do something like this without good result.

```js
let country = 'spain';

const List = ({ matchs }) => {

  return (
        <div>
        {matchs.map((match) =>

          let my_filter = match.players.filter(player => player.country === country);
          {my_filter ? (
            
            <div className="match" key={match.id}>
            
              <div className="id">{match.id}</div>

              <div className="players">

                {match.players.map((player, num) =>
                  <div className="player" key={num}>
                    <span className="player-country">{player.country}></span>
                    <span className="name">{player.name}</span> 
                  </div>
                )}
                    
            </div>
          
           ) : ()}
        )}
        </div>
  );

}
```

What would be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can u explain what is exactly you want to do at the end ?

Comment: What should be the result when you filtered using `spain` in your object??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `filter` matchs first (by player's country) and then `map` through the results:

```
<div>
{matchs
  .filter(match => match.players.find(player => player.country === country))
  .map(match =>
    <div className="match" key={match.id}>
      ...
    </div>
  )}
</div>
```